# Position elements inside a List Group item

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm quite new to Bootstrap, so sorry if this sounds too basic.

I need to create a ListGroup.

Each item in the list should contain:

1. a text;
2. a couple of radios input (horizontal inline);
3. a button;

Text, radios and the button should be spaced so that the text takes 80% of the available space and radios/button each 10%.

Is this possible? How?

Comment: using grid layout provided with bootstrap u can arrange your item as u want refer this https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/

Comment: @DeepakVerma Ok, thank you

Comment: happy to help !! :)

Answer (score 0):

I just created a linear grid for you using most commonly used classes in `Bootstrap 4`. What do you think? I have attached the link to CodePen below, so you can start using it straight away.

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="main-wrapper">
  <div class="container main-container">
    <div class="row main-row">
      <div class="col-12 align-center">
        <div class="row p-3">
          <div class="col-4 align-middle">
            This is a sample text
          </div>
          <div class="col-6">
            <div class="form-check-inline">
              <label class="form-check-label">
    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="optradio">Option 1
  </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check-inline">
              <label class="form-check-label">
    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="optradio">Option 2
  </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check-inline disabled">
              <label class="form-check-label">
    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="optradio" disabled>Option 3
  </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-2">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Button</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row main-row">
      <div class="col-12 align-center">
        <div class="row p-3">
          <div class="col-4 align-middle">
            This is a sample text
          </div>
          <div class="col-6">
            <div class="form-check-inline">
              <label class="form-check-label">
    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="optradio">Option 1
  </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check-inline">
              <label class="form-check-label">
    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="optradio">Option 2
  </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check-inline disabled">
              <label class="form-check-label">
    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="optradio" disabled>Option 3
  </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-2">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-block">Button</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row main-row">
      <div class="col-12 align-center">
        <div class="row p-3">
          <div class="col-4 align-middle">
            This is a sample text
          </div>
          <div class="col-6">
            <div class="form-check-inline">
              <label class="form-check-label">
    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="optradio">Option 1
  </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check-inline">
              <label class="form-check-label">
    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="optradio">Option 2
  </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check-inline disabled">
              <label class="form-check-label">
    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="optradio" disabled>Option 3
  </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-2">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Button</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row main-row">
      <div class="col-12 align-center">
        <div class="row p-3">
          <div class="col-4 align-middle">
            This is a sample text
          </div>
          <div class="col-6">
            <div class="form-check-inline">
              <label class="form-check-label">
    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="optradio">Option 1
  </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check-inline">
              <label class="form-check-label">
    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="optradio">Option 2
  </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check-inline disabled">
              <label class="form-check-label">
    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="optradio" disabled>Option 3
  </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-2">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-block">Button</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row main-row">
      <div class="col-12 align-center">
        <div class="row p-3">
          <div class="col-4 align-middle">
            This is a sample text
          </div>
          <div class="col-6">
            <div class="form-check-inline">
              <label class="form-check-label">
    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="optradio">Option 1
  </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check-inline">
              <label class="form-check-label">
    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="optradio">Option 2
  </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check-inline disabled">
              <label class="form-check-label">
    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="optradio" disabled>Option 3
  </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-2">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block">Button</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.main-wrapper {
  background-color: #f8f9fa
}
.main-container {
  margin-top: 50px;    
  padding: 10px
}

.row.main-row {
  background-color: #ddd;  
  margin: 10px; 
  border: 5px solid #eee
}
```

**Link to CodePen**

https://codepen.io/anjanasilva/pen/PyzQWX

I hope this helps. Thank you.

Comment: It's very good, even if I need the options near the button, not the text   :-)

Comment: (options = radios)

Comment: Thanks @IanBell. I have used `col-4` for the text, `col-6` for radio buttons and `col-2` the button (sums up to col-12). Try increasing / decreasing the col width.  (min `col-1` and max `col-12`, total needs to be 12 though).